# Cannot change Tabs text and icon colors in KivyMD

Tags: tabs, kivy-language, kivymd

Iam trying to learn how to program with KivyMD. After doing some research and watching some tutorials iam putting a GUI together with the trail-and-error approach.

At the moment iam trying to change the colors of the Tab text and icons. After hours of online searching iam still not able to change them. The `text_color_normal:`and `text_color_active:` in the .kv file simply
seems to have no effect on them. I have the feeling iam doing something fundamentally wrong here. Can somebody give me some tips how to proceed? Main.py and .KV file are below.

Thanks in advance!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.font_definitions import fonts
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


Window.size = (300, 500) # voor develop doeleinden mobielscherm


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class Screen3(Screen):
    pass


class Screen4(Screen):
    pass


class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class Tab1(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        screen = Builder.load_file('demo_file.kv')

        return screen

    def navigation_draw(self):
        print('navigation')


DemoApp().run()
```

demo_file.kv

```
Screen:
    NavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id:screen_manager

            Screen1:
                name: 'home_screen'

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Home'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        elevation: 0
                        specific_text_color: 0,0,0,1

                    MDTabs:
                        id:android_tabs
                        tab_bar_height: '35dp'
                        background_color: 1,0,0,0.85
                        elevation: 0
                        text_color_normal: 0, 1, 0, 1
                        text_color_active: 1, 0, 0, 1
                        color_indicator: 0.95, 0.95, 0.1, 1

                        Tab:
                            text: 'Tab1'

                        Tab1:
                            text: 'chart-pie'

                    MDBottomAppBar:

                        MDToolbar:
                            title: 'Start sessie'
                            mode: 'end'
                            type: 'bottom'
                            on_action_button: app.navigation_draw()
                            icon: 'beer'
                            icon_color: 0.95, 0.95, 0.1, 1

            Screen2:
                name: 'profile_screen'

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Profiel'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        elevation: 7
                    Widget:

            Screen3:
                name: 'session_screen'

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Sessies'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        elevation: 10
                    Widget:


            Screen4:
                name: 'logout_screen'

                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDToolbar:
                        title: 'Uitloggen'
                        left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
                        elevation: 10
                    Widget:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id:nav_drawer

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: '8dp'
                padding: '8dp'

                Image:
                    source: 'avatar.jpg'

                MDLabel:
                    text: '     Name'
                    front_style: 'Subtitle1'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]

                MDLabel:
                    text: '     email@hotmail.com'
                    front_style: 'Caption'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]

                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Profiel'
                            on_press: screen_manager.current = 'profile_screen'
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'face-profile'
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = 'profile_screen'


                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Drink sessies'
                            on_press: screen_manager.current = 'session_screen'
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'beer'
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = 'session_screen'

                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Uitloggen'
                            on_press: screen_manager.current = 'logout_screen'
                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'logout'
                                on_press: screen_manager.current = 'logout_screen'

<Tab>:

    MDLabel:

        text:'tab1'
        user_font_size: "48sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

<Tab1>:

    MDLabel:

        text:'tab2'
        user_font_size: "48sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the color of the text/icon of the tabs? That is working for me.

Maybe try reinstall KivyMD.

Comment: Yes i tried to edit the colors by using `text_color_normal` and `text_color_active` under `Tab` and `Tab1` but sadly without effect. Offcourse with the right indentation. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Under MDTabs. Not the individual tabs. You have it already in your code. Or are you trying change individual tabs?

Comment: No iam trying to change the colors of the icon and text on all the tabs. The code i have already written under MDTabs does not have any effect on the text or icons of the tabs. Could you tell me a little more about the way you change the colors?

Comment: Your code, red and green [Example1](https://i.imgur.com/m88pSEr.jpg) 
Changed in blue [Example2](https://i.imgur.com/IXhqOe0.jpg)

Comment: The weird thing is... i have the exact same code but it does not work in my application. I can change the color of the indicator but not the text. I think something is wrong with my kivymy. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out why my code was not working. While searching the web i stumbled across the change logs and i found out that the unreleased version contains a fix for `text_color_normal` and `text_color_active`. Which means that in my current version (0.104.1) the parameters did not work the way they should. Installing KivyMD with `pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip` works for me.

Thanks for your effort to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

test this instead :  `text_color : rgba(253, 0, 253,255)`
it's worked for me